# how to run android app in Chromebase Commercial

Tags: android, android-studio

I know not all developers faced the same before but i have a Chromebase Commercial device http://www.aopen.com/us/chromebase-commercial and i want to install an android app to it either from google play store or direct installation from android studio or anything else . so does any one has any idea about it

Comment: did you ever get android apps installed ?